# Incremental Loading and snapped visual state

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, gridview, windows-store-apps

I have a listview(for snapped state) and a gridview(for normal state) in my app page (which is an **items page template**) and they are both bound to a collection that implements `ISupportIncrementalLoading` interface. Here are the implemented methods:

```
public HasMoreItemsDelegate MoreItemsExist { get; set; }
        public LoadMoreItemsDelegate<T> ItemsLoadAsync { get; set; }

        public bool HasMoreItems
        {
            get 
            {
                return this.MoreItemsExist();
            }
        }

        private bool isLoading;

        public bool IsLoading
        {
            get
            {
                return this.isLoading;
            }
            private set
            {
                this.isLoading = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("IsLoading");
            }
        }

        public Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count)
        {
            if (this.IsLoading)
            {
               throw new InvalidOperationException("Only one operation in flight at a time");
            }
            this.IsLoading = true;
            return AsyncInfo.Run((c) => LoadMoreItemsAsync(c, count));
        }

        async Task<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(CancellationToken c, uint count)
        {
            try
            {
                IEnumerable<T> itemsToAdd = await ItemsLoadAsync(c, count);
                foreach (var item in itemsToAdd)
                {
                    this.Add(item);
                }
                return new LoadMoreItemsResult { Count = (uint)itemsToAdd.Count() };
            }
            finally
            {
                this.IsLoading = false;
            }
        }
```

The problem I encounter is: When the app is in snapped mode and I navigate to the page with the listview and gridview, BOTH views try to call `LoadMoreItemsAsync` and I enter the exception clause, whereas when in normal (fullscreen) mode, only the gridview calls the method, and the listview doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from how the template works. The gridview is Visible by default and the listview is not. When we navigate to the page, the `VisualStateManager` is called **AFTER** the page is rendered, and therefore when navigated to, the gridview is visible for a short time and calls the `LoadMoreItemsAsync` method before it gets hidden. After the storyboard is complete, the listview gets shown and also calls the `LoadMoreItemsAsync` and the problem occurs.

How I solved it: Made both views Collapsed by default and handled when they are shown in the `VisualStateManager` (it's ALWAYS called after navigating to the page).